# save image from <notesbitmap> in dxl file to local machine , c#

Tags: c#, .net, lotus-notes

Subject: how to save image from notesbitmap tag of dxl file on local machine

Product Area: Lotus Notes Client

### how can i save image from dxl to local machine , c#

I have dxl file and i want save image on local machine, even thogh i have set dxlExporter.ConvertNotesbitmapsToGIF = true;

i am getting image tag as follows.

notesbitmap

```
xP8gAAEAAQAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAU1RHNjI2NTeVACYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0wF/
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

notesbitmap

with following dxl - nodes

1) notesbitmap

notesbitmap

```
xP8gAAEAAQAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAU1RHNjI2NTeVACYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0wF/
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

notesbitmap

2) filedata

file

filedata

```
AQAYCQEAmQAcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAH0AHAAAAAEA0wF/ANMIAAABAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAB8AN4IAADTCNQIR0lGODlh0wF/AOcAANDQyICAgAAAAEBAQP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+CHL/745Jdv/vno
p6/++teVfvr74bkP//zIyU///YtvviT+/H9nf/8AdM3/AkhAwemvS50roALZMsAFOtAsDXygBMMS
wQlakCsVvKAGTeW4DXowSQcUVNkwQ0iURRKRW8lggA6JF1QiSZWujCVPYCnLWtKylrG8
JS5RqctdwrGXvnQhMIPpwWESE1SZS6Yyl4m5BHXwmPtK2wvz1hNjQrNS0nyV5p55TXplczaMq6Yi
dZXAbtrqm5HrIR6VEs5ZjpMugqgBBaoojGaUoG1pp0UH6tF2aVQuImXPO9cF0pI66qRxSWlOrOlS
LQlgADjNqU53ytOe+vSnQA0qTjnKqZrikqZGnR9Sk/q+pTLVdE59quiiKlXPUbWqj8OXULfK1a56
9atgDatYx0rWspr1rGhNq1rXyta2etV6cI2rXOdK17ra9a54zate98rXvvr1rzIJCAA7Pw==
```

filedata

file

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003916/lotus-notes-dxl-notesbitmap-to-gif/12036237#12036237

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the information found in this question/answer? [Lotus Notes DXL Notesbitmap to GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003916/lotus-notes-dxl-notesbitmap-to-gif)

Use any online Base64 decoder to see the STG-filename in the first Notesbitmap-element, and then find that element in the DXL file.